# How can be count the String with a Substring and then the return the matching characters

Tags: c, string, count, match

I want to count the String with SubString by matching it and the return it at the end so first i try to match the single character in the String but i am not able to match the String with it so can anyone help me in it because i am just a beginner.i just want to match the string with a substring and try to return it how many time the substring is Present in String 
here i am also giving my code in support e.g.
example 1
input:-abcabcabcabc 
input of substring:-abc 
output :-4
example 2
input:-abcdefghabcd 
input for substring :-zabc 
output:0
example 3
input:-abcababcd 
input for substring:-cd 
output:-1

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[50],ch;
    int i,count=0;

    printf("enter a string");
    gets(str);
    printf("enter a character which u want to find ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);

    for(i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==ch)
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: You question is not clear. Can you post few examples (string, substring and expected result). The question refers to substring, but the sample code only looks for single character

Comment: Break this problem down into smaller parts. You don't need to use input when starting, just use constants, your problem solving will be faster. For a simpler problem, try to find the count of just one character in the string.

Comment: Is the problem that you `return` from main without calling `printf("count=%i.\n", i);` or similar? You probably want to return an exit code, anyway.